# Get current directory and run a File in vbscript?

Tags: vb.net, iis, vbscript

I am trying to see if IIS is installed and display a message and a download exe to INstall IIS if IIS isn't installed.However i am having a hard time running a file without specifying the full path in the vb-script.The path will be dynamic and it impossible to specify any other directory than "%cd%

My code:

```
If WScript.Arguments.length =0 Then
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

objShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", Chr(34) & _
WScript.ScriptFullName & Chr(34) & " uac", "", "runas", 1
Else
Dim intCounter, strSubkey
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
strComputer = "."

Set objReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
& strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft"

objReg.EnumKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, arrSubKeys

intCounter=0
For Each subkey In arrSubKeys
If subkey="InetStp" Then
 intCounter=1 or  strSubkey=subkey
End If

Next
currentDirectory = left(WScript.ScriptFullName, Len(WScript.ScriptFullName))-(len(WScript.ScriptName)))

if intCounter=0 then
Set WSHShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
WSHShell.Run ("\currentDirectory\noiisinstalled.exe") 
Elseif intCounter=1 then
Wscript.Echo "IIS is Already installed - " & strSubkey
End If
End if
```

My problem is running the  no iisinstalled.exe file.Whatever I'm trying the script cannot find the file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the current directory using the [`Scripting.FileSystemObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50(v=VS.85).aspx). ie

```
dim fso: set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' directory in which this script is currently running
CurrentDirectory = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
```

to use this to build a new path, you can use the `BuildPath()` function

```
NewPath = fso.BuildPath(CurrentDirectory, "noiisinstalled.exe")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Set WSHShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
sCurrentDirectory = WSHShell.CurrentDirectory & "\"
```